# image url can't be get from firebase storage to firestore database

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I tried to store image to firebase storage and try to get an image URL to the database these are the codes.
this is the code that I used to upload the image to firebase storage.

```
   uploadNotice()async{

   String fileName=basename(noticepic.path);
  final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef=FirebaseStorage.instance
  .ref().child('cisnotices/$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(noticepic);
    var dowurl = await (await task.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    var url=dowurl.toString();
    noticeProvider.changePhotoUrl(url).then((val){
        print('photo url got');
      }).catchError((e){
        print(e);
      });



}
NoticeProvider noticeProvider=NoticeProvider();
```

here is the `noticeprovider.dart` I used to change the image URL

```
class NoticeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final firestoreService=FirestoreService();

 String _noticeId;
 String _userName;
 String _userPost;
 String _date; 
 String _photoUrl;
 var uuid=Uuid();

 //getters

 String get userName => _userName;
 String get userPost => _userPost;
 String get date => _date;
 String get photoUrl => _photoUrl;

 //setters

  changeUserName(String value){
  _userName=value;
 notifyListeners();
 }
  changeUserPost(String value){
 _userPost=value;
  notifyListeners();
 }
  changeDate(String value){
  _date=value;
  notifyListeners();
}
 changePhotoUrl(String value){
  _photoUrl=value;
  notifyListeners();
}

 saveNotice(){
  var newNotice=Notice(userName: userName,userPost: userPost,photoUrl: photoUrl,
  date: date,noticeId: uuid.v4());
  firestoreService.saveNotice(newNotice);


 }



 }
```

here is `firestoreservice.dart`

```
  class FirestoreService {
 Firestore _db=Firestore.instance;

  Future<void> saveNotice(Notice notice){
     return _db.collection('notices').document(notice.noticeId).setData(notice.toMap());
  }

  }
```

image is saved in firebase storage, but the URL can't get to the database. it always shows 'null'.

Comment: Most likely the download URL hasn't been determined yet when you save the notice. How do the first `uploadNotice` snippet and the other snippets relate? I don't see any call to `saveNotice` in here.

Comment: i called saveNotice when user press upload button to upload all details of the form. all other details appear on database except photoUrl

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to upload image/File and get it's Download URL

```
 final StorageReference storageReferencem = FirebaseStorage()
      .ref()
      .child("Users/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}");
  final StorageUploadTask uploadTaskm =
  storageReferencem.putFile(croppedFile);
  await uploadTaskm.onComplete;
  await storageReferencem.getDownloadURL().then((url) {
    URL=url;
  });
```